# Unable to look up other files in appspot.com - problem with app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine

I have these files: `index.php`, `filecallup.js`, `image.png`, `userprofile.php` deployed in my `xxx.appspot.com`.

The `index.php` file is expected to collect some URL query variables and open the `userprofile.php`.

My problem is that when I click on the link (https://xxx.appspot.com/?user=peter) it still points to the index.php file and doesn't load `userprofile.php`.

I think it's a problem with my `app.yaml` file because it renders well in other servers except for GAE.

Here is the `app.yaml` code:

```
#Use the PHP 7.3 runtime (BETA) by replacing "php72" below with "php73"
runtime: php72
#entrypoint: serve main.php
service: default
#threadsafe: true

handlers:
# Serve a directory as a static resource.
#- url: /stylesheets
#  static_dir: stylesheets

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
static_files: \1
upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$

- url: /(.+\.(htm|html|css|js))$
static_files: \1
upload: .+\.(htm|html|css|js)$

# Serve your app through a front controller at index.php or public/index.php.
- url: /mail.php
script: auto
```

Here is the `index.php` code:

```
<?php
some codes here`
header('Location:userprofile.php')
>?
```

Comment: Try changing the last part of your app.yaml from `-url: /mail.php` to `-url: .*` or `-url: /.* `

Comment: Tnx Daniel for your contribution. i tried already but not working

Comment: Could you check your logs for any possible errors when you click on the troublesome link and share them on the post? Are you able to see the userprofile.php file under the source files (if you click on Tools -> Debug under the App Engine's Versions page)? Notice that in the App Engine setting your application is responsible fro starting a webserver and handling the requests. You could use the Slim framework to handle the request as stated on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/how-requests-are-handled#handling_requests).